# Extract elements of curl request

Tags: php, instagram

I have some curl code and when I run it and echo $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch), the following is printed. How would I individually extract the elements from this?

```
httpresponse{"access_token":"233408318.617bf98.6adcf10f06d04f8ca7d66ccb61a829ba","user":{"username":"jsniff","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","full_name":"","id":"233408318"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode` will get the job done if you parse out the `"httpresponse"` leading the `{`

Try:

```
print_r(json_decode(substr($httpResponse,12)));
```

You can access the objects:

```
$responseObj=json_decode(substr($httpResponse,12));
echo $responseObj->user->username;
```